# Code gives "ImportError: No module named 'file2'" in Python 3, but works perfectly in Python 2.7

Tags: python, flask

I have created a flask app, in `Python 2.7`. The project structure is like this:

```
Flask_Directory/
    app.py
    sub_dir/
        file1.py
        file2.py
        __init__.py
```

---

`app.py` imports `file1` like this:

```
from sub_dir import file1
```

`file1.py` imports `file2.py` like this:

```
from file2 import *
```

---

When I run `app.py`, code is working fine in `Python 2.7`, but in `Python 3`, the same structure is giving an error in `file1.py`:

```
ImportError: No module named 'file2'
```

Can anybody help, what I am missing?

Comment: try `import sub_dir.file2 as whatever_this_could_be`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> from file2 import *

What you did is called `Implicit Relative Import`.

---

`Implicit Relative Imports` have been deprecated in `Python 3`.

Why?

- One of the reasons is that if there is a Python package/module with the same name, then it (the wrong one) might be imported.

---

You have two options:

1. `from sub_dir.file2 import *` (This is called `Absolute Import`.)
2. `from .file2 import *` (This is called `Explicit Relative Import`.)

Also, you might want to read: [Absolute vs Relative Imports in Python](https://realpython.com/absolute-vs-relative-python-imports/) and [PEP 8 imports](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#imports).

---

**Note: Using `import *` is discouraged.**

Answer (score 1):

You can call the `sub_dir` folder first then the `file2.py`

```
import sub_dir.file2 as FILE2

// then use FILE2 e.g.
FILE2.function_in_file2()
```

Answer (score 1):

In Python3 , We need to access the the class along with the module name.
Eg:
    app module (must have **init**.py) -> module1 - > demo.py

You have to use use **from app.module1 import demo as demo**